# google geocoding - get all possible localities for street

Tags: google-geocoding-api

Is there any way to look up a Street\Road and get all possible localities (suburbs) for it.
I.e. if a long street goes through multiple localities. Can I get a list of all of them?

Currently I just get what seems to be the most important locality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ending up contacting google maps technical support.  Short answer... No. Not current possible.

> Maps Support: Currently, we do not offer that feature.
>
> Maps Support: Nor do I personally know any reliable workarounds for
> it.

:(